# Docker: Deploy php application container without using volume

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I'm working on a full-stack web application, which is  containing an angular2 frontend, php backend and a mongodb database.
These are running at the moment on an windows server, using WAMP (http://www.wampserver.com/en/). 
I want to dockerize this stack and end up having three running docker containers on the windows server.
For deployment I want to use a gitlab repository, where the docker images shall be hosted.

I've searched for tutorials about dockerize an php application, but they all rely on using the volume of the server. 
Downloading and executing an single docker-compose.yml file for deployment seems totally fine to me, but I don't want to deploy code to the server.

Here is an example docker-compose file from an tutorial:(https://www.cloudreach.com/blog/containerize-this-php-apache-mysql-within-docker-containers/)

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  php:
    build: './php/'
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
  apache:
    build: './apache/'
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6.40
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

The docker-compose file is capable of pulling from private repositories. 
Therefore I want to use such an file to download and set up the three containers. But in the examples the code seems to be needed on the server. The images are build locally, which I want to avoid totally.

So my questing is: 
Is there a way for hosting an php backend container with apache or nginx, without using the volume?

Comment: As in without using the volume, specifically on the web server container? I'm assuming you'd still want it on the php container? If so, depending on how the web server is configured you might just be able to remove the volumes part of the apache section.

Comment: Well, yes, I want the php container to be built locally on my working PC and then shipped via the gitlab repo to the server. The docker-compose file shall pull it from there. But is there a way the web server container don't have to use the volume?

Comment: Like I said. It depends on your config. E.g. if your webserver simply proxies all requests straight to PHP(-FPM?), without touching the volume, then it's not needed anyway.

Comment: Is your question actually how can you get docker-compose to use the images you've pushed to gitlab rather than rebuilding?

Comment: Great, thanks for your hint for directly proxiing to PHP. Yes, I guess I wasn't sure about the acutal problem.